# WinDivert: What is the reason behind the error message "error: failed to open Divert device (110)"?

Tags: winapi, packet-capture

I tried to install WinDivert in my machine (Windows 7 64-bit OS). I tried with both 32-bit and 64-bit version. However, I failed at both of the cases and received the error message: "error: failed to open Divert device (110)". I followed Section 2 (Steps 2.1 and 2.2) of the tutorial:  http://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html. I used "Free Build Environment" (x86/x64). I invoked wddk-build.bat. Then I signed the driver as it has been shown in the document (just as it is written). I restarted the machine and tried to run "netdump" and "netfilter" from "install/WDDK/..." from the command prompt. However, nothing works for me. Even I tried with the MS Visual Studio 10 (masvc-build.bat). What is the issue, I am suffering with?

Comment: Did you enable test-signing on your machine during boot?

Comment: Yes I did. However, at last I have found the problem. The driver somehow could not start. I have used "sc start WinDivert.sys" to start the service manually 
. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinDivert 110 error usually indicates that the driver failed to load.  This can be caused by a number of different things.  The checklist for a WinDivert (110) errors would be:

1. Make sure that you are using the 64-bit driver only for 64-bit systems, and the 32-bit only for 32-bit systems
2. Make sure the driver is properly signed (or test-signed with Windows test-mode enabled)
3. Make sure the WinDivert driver files (WinDivert.sys, WinDivert.inf, WdfCoInstaller*.dll) are in your program's directory when DivertOpen() is called.
4. Make sure you are running the program with Administrator privileges.

Usually one of the above is causing the problem.

EDIT: Some stubborn 110 errors can be fixed by manually stopping/starting the WinDivert service, e.g. by running the following commands as Administrator:

`sc stop WinDivert1.0`
`sc delete WinDivert1.0`

EDIT (2): Note that WinDivert (110) errors have been replaced with more meaningful error codes in version 1.0.3 and above.